# What does it mean that there is an "isomorphism of homsets" due to an exponential object?

Tags: category-theory

$X^Y$ together with a morphism $\bf{ apply}$ $:X^Y\times Y\to X$ is an exponential object of $X$ and $Y$ if for each $Z$ and each morphism $f:Z\times Y \to X$, there is a unique morphism $\lambda f:Z\to X^Y$ such that $\lambda f \times id_Y \circ \bf {apply}$ $ = f$.

It is obvious that for every $f$ there is a $\lambda f$. But two things are not obvious to me:

- Is there necessarily for every morphism $\lambda g:Z\to X^Y$ a corresponding morphism $g:Z\times Y \to X$? Couldn't we have a category where there are these $\lambda f:Z\to X^Y$, but also additional extraneous morphisms $\lambda g:Z\to X^Y$ that have no corresponding $g$? Can't we always add such extraneous morphisms?
- Assuming that the previous question is clarified, and there is indeed a bijection between these homsets, why does [wikipedia call it a "isomorphism" of homsets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_object)? An isomorphism is only an isomorphism within a category, and I don't know what category they're talking about.

Comment: I don't mean to offend, but you've asked a lot of questions tonight which would be covered by any introductory text on the subject. Tom Leinster's *Basic Category Theory* has a freely downloadable version available on the Arxiv, and you might benefit from actually spending some time with it. As it stands, it feels like you're skimming Wikipedia and then asking us to do the work of a textbook.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine, I am reading a textbook, and following lectures. I just find some of it hard enough to follow that I'm confused.

Answer (score 3):

(i) : No : start from $h : Z\to X^Y$; then you have $h\times id_Y : Z\times Y\to X^Y\times Y$, and then you can compose with $\mathbf{apply}$ to get $g:= \mathbf{apply}\circ (h\times id_Y) : Z\times Y\to X$.

Then by uniqueness, $\lambda g = h$.

(ii) : A bijection between sets is an isomorphism in the category of sets $\mathbf{Set}$.

But here it's even lore than that, because the isomorphism $\hom(Z\times Y, X) \cong \hom(Z, X^Y)$ is natural in all three variables, so it is actually an isomorphism between two functors in the category of functors $C^{op}\times C^{op}\times C\to \mathbf{Set}$